# Getting NPE When Applying Arguments to Curried Fn

Tags: scala

I wrote a simple function:

```
scala> def f(x: Int)(y: Int): Int = x + y
f: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int
```

Then I assigned the `def` to a `val`.

```
scala> val g: Int => Int => Int = f
g: Int => (Int => Int) = null
```

Finally I tried to run it against `f`.

```
scala> f(10)(20)
java.lang.NullPointerException
  ... 33 elided
```

The same thing happens when applying `(10)(20)` to `g`:

```
scala> g(10)(20)
java.lang.NullPointerException
  ... 33 elided
```

Why the NPE here?

Comment: What version is this? I don't see any NPE in 2.11.5

Comment: `Scala code runner version 2.11.4`

Comment: This works as expected for me.  Is there more context you could provide?  If you start a new REPL and run those exact lines, you get an NPE?

Comment: Something's weird there. For me it's not "g: Int => (Int => Int) = null" but "g: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>". Which is better.